# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY with intent pointing to external activity doesn't work. Is that possible?

Tags: android

I need to give the user some instructions on how to change some settings. To do that, I launch an intent to start the settings action, than, launch an activity that will overlay it with some transparencies and instructions.

In code, it translates to something like:

```
startActivity(new Intent("settingsName").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY));

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent overlayIntent = new Intent(callerActivity, SettingsOverlayActivity.class));
        callerActivity.startActivity(overlayIntent);

    }
}, 500);
```

When adding the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, I expected the user to go back to the caller activity when pressing the back button, like in the image:

[image]

Sadly, I can't achieve this behaviour simple using flags on the activities. I tried all kind of combinations that I was able to think of: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, and a bunch of others, but with no success. When pressing the back button on the overlay, I am being always redirected to the Settings screen.

My workaround was to send BaseActivity.class as a parameter to OverlayActivity, and overriding the onBackPressed to reorder BaseActivity to front. Translating to code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Class callerActivity = (Class) getIntent().getExtras().get(OVERLAY_CALLER_ACTIVITY_KEY);
    if(callerActivity != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, callerActivity).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT));
        return;
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Please ignore null-checks, checks for the activity integrity and others, I tried to make the code as small as possible.

The point is: my workaround looks a lot with a "hack" and I really think that there is a more elegant solution for this. Can someone point me the correct way to achieve the behaviour?

Comment: "When adding the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, I expected the user to go back to the caller activity when pressing the back button" -- that's not what [that flag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) does. If anything, I would have expected the Settings activity to be destroyed once your overlay was started. "I really think that there is a more elegant solution for this" -- I would be fairly surprised if that were the case.

Comment: @CommonsWare. What I think is happening is that as the Settings is an activity external from my App, it's being added to another task stack, even without the NEW_TASK FLAG. That's why it's not destroyed when OverlayActivity starts (even with no history) and I don't seem to find a reliable way to confirm and work around this.

Comment: "it's being added to another task stack, even without the NEW_TASK FLAG" -- that is very possible. A bunch of Settings activities use task affinities for that.